# recebo exited with non-zero status nesse codigo pq?

Tags: c, sintaxe

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int i,jog,rod,placar[500],ponto=0,p,maxPonto=0,vencedor=0,rodCopia;

  scanf("%d %d",&jog,&rod);

  rodCopia = rod;

  for(i=1;i<=jog;i++){
          scanf("%d",&p);
          placar[i]+=p;
       if(i==jog && rod>0){
         rod-=1;
         i = 0;
       }

  }
       for(i=1;i<=rodCopia;i++){
         if(maxPonto < placar[i]){
           maxPonto = placar[i];
           vencedor = i;
         }

       }


     printf(vencedor); 
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: O ultimo `printf` é suposto ser `printf("%d",vencedor);`. Quais os dados de entrada que está a utilizar ? O que o programa deveria fazer que não faz ?

Comment: Tem como fornecer um exemplo de entrada?

Answer (score 0):

O problema no seu código está na parte em que inicia o for a partir de 1, a linguagem C não permite que um vetor tenha a usa posição zero nula, sendo assim o seu primeiro for, assim como o segundo ignora a posição 0 do vetor. Para corrigir o problema inicie o i do for como 0 e ao invés de deixar "<=" deixe só menor

Segue o código arrumado

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int i,jog,rod,placar[500],ponto=0,p,maxPonto=0,vencedor=0,rodCopia;

  scanf("%d %d",&jog,&rod);

  rodCopia = rod;

  for(i=0;i<jog;i++){
    printf("Ok");
          scanf("%d",&p);
          placar[i]+=p;
       if(i==jog && rod>0){
         rod-=1;
         i = 0;
       }

  }
       for(i=0;i<rodCopia;i++){
         if(maxPonto < placar[i]){
           maxPonto = placar[i];
           vencedor = i;
         }

       }


     printf(vencedor); 
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Na verdade depende da entrada para estourar em `jog` ou `rod`. Se o AP estiver fazendo na mão, ele não vai testar com números grandes, no máximo algumas dezenas, o que então descartaria sua resposta. Também tem o caso de que se a entrada for `100000` a sua solução também irá quebrar. O mais provável é o que o @Isac apontou no comentário, que você replicou aqui